# VBA download xlsx file from website with variable name

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I am struggling to download a file that is updated daily with a time stamp, any help greatly appreciated

I would like to refer to the tag name or something so that I don't need to include the time stamp

```
'Create InternetExplorer Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "https://my.euroclear.com/content/dam/euroclear/synchronization/eui_growth_%20market_stamp_exemption/GrowthMarkets_StampExemption_13062019_093138.xlsx": Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
Application.SendKeys "%{S}", True
```

Perhaps something like this?

I think something like this should work but I can't get it working:

```
Sub File() 
Const URL = "my.euroclear.com/eui/en/reference/public/…" 
Dim http As New XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument, post As Object, i As Integer 

With http .Open "GET", URL, False .send 
html.body.innerHTML = .responseText 
End 

With For Each post In html.getElementsByClassName("downloads")(0).getElementsByTagName("li") 

    With post.getElementsByTagName("a") 
        If .Length Then i = i + 1: Cells(i, 1) = .Item(0).innerText 
    End With 

Next post 

End Sub
```

Comment: https://my.euroclear.com/eui/en/reference/public/growth-market-stamp-exemption.html  -  link to webpage

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

As far as I know, you must use the entire URL, otherwise VBA won't know where to download from. An option would be to make the link dynamic, and use a little user input for the timestamp (and possibly the date too)

I have made use of an inputbox so the user can enter the file's timestamp. I hope this helps making the download of the file more dynamic. For the date, the current date is used. You could of course change this to another date.

```
Dim URL As String
Dim Extension As String
Dim TimeStamp As Variant

URL = "https://my.euroclear.com/content/dam/euroclear/synchronization/eui_growth_%20market_stamp_exemption/GrowthMarkets_StampExemption_"
Extension = ".xlsx"
DayStamp = Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy") & "_"
TimeStamp = InputBox("Enter the file's timestamp in hhmmss")

'Create InternetExplorer Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate URL & DayStamp & TimeStamp & Extension

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
Application.SendKeys "%{S}", True
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick response but I was intending to automate this and so the use of an input box would be slower than just downloading the file myself. I believe it should be possibly by using html element class or similar.

Comment: I am not sure how to automate it without knowing the date and time stamp. Do you mean to find the file with the most recent stamp, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
Dim downloadlink As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim IE As Object

'Create InternetExplorer Object
 Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 IE.Visible = True: IE.Navigate "https://my.euroclear.com/eui/en/reference/public/growth-market-stamp-exemption.html": While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend: Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")

'Downloads all Reports
Set downloadlink = Nothing
i = 0
While i < IE.document.Links.Length And downloadlink Is Nothing
    If Left(IE.document.Links(i).innerText, 13) = "Current data:" Then 
    IE.document.Links(i).Click: Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"): 
    Application.SendKeys "%{S}", True
    i = i + 1
Wend
IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```